# Data base structure of a subscriber list

Tags: database-design

I am building a application that allow different user to store the subscriber information

- To store the subscriber information , the user first create a list
  For each list, there is a ListID.

`Subscriber` may have different attribute : email phone fax ....

For each list,  their setting is different , so a `require_attribute table` is introduced.
It is a bridge between subscriber and List

That store `Listid ,subid , attribute, datatype`

**That means the system have a lot of list, each user have their own list, and the list have different attribute, some list have email , phone , some may have phone, address, name mail.. And the datatype is different, some may use 'name' as integer , some may use 'name'
as varchar**

- attribute means email phone, it is to define for `which list have
  which subscriber attribute`
- datatype means for each attribute, what is its datatype

  ```
  Table :subscriber :        
  Field :subid , name,email

  Table :Require Attribute:

  Field : Listid ,subid , attribute, datatype
  ```

The attribute here is {name, email}

So a simple data is

```
Subscriber: 1 , MYname, Myemail

Require Attribute :

 Listid , 1 , 'email', 'intger'

 Listid , 1 , 'name', 'varchar'
```

I found that this kind of storage is too complex too handle with,  Since the subscriber is share to every body, so if a person want to change the datatype of name, it will also affect the data of the other user.

Simple error situation:

Subscriber:

```
list1,  Subscriber 1 , name1, email1

list2, Subscriber 2  , name2 , email2

Require Attribute :

     List1 , Subscriber 1 , 'email', 'varchar',

     List1 , Subscriber 1  , 'name', 'varchar', 

     Listid , Subscriber 2 , 'email', 'varchar', 

     Listid , Subscriber 2, 'name', 'integer',
```

**if user B change the data type of name in require attribute from varchar to integer, it cause a problem. becasue list 1 is own by user A , he want the datatype is varchar, but list 2 is won by user B , he want the datatype to be integer**

So how can i redesign the structure?

Answer (score 1):

No RDBMS system I know of supports mixing a data-type within a single column. So I think you've got two solutions:

1. Separate tables - each user's list gets their own Database table. This would allow you the flexibility to customize the data type at the column level.
2. Flexible data type in the "name" column. You could use a `varchar` or even a binary `blob` in the name column and allow the user to store whatever they want in that column. Then, at the application level, you could interpret that data in whatever format you like by, for instance, casting it to an integer.

It sounds to me, since you're hoping to store different types of data with different structures to it, that you should probably just be using separate tables.

Comment: Jeff Allen - Welcome to DBA.SE.  I think you've got the start of a pretty good answer to this question - so +1.  You might consider expanding the pros and cons of each approach or even just clarifying why you recommended option 1.  Fully developed answers attract more up-votes and help you build your rep.